# unstaking wax problem in eosauthority

Tags: unstake

i was unstaking wax in eosauthority, i waited 3 days after that i clicked the manually refund and it says Transaction failed - assertion failure with message: refund is not available yet.

Comment: Please leave additional information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.